# Grouping and number rows separated by a blank row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping to get some help automating a process that takes a lot of time. Basically I have a report where groups of related rows are separated by a blank row. I would like to have a way to identify or assign a number to each group either with a formula or macro. The end goal would be to have a sum for each separate group. There is essentially no other way to distinguish what goes in each group aside from the fact that they are separated by a blank row. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming data starts on row 3 this formula will work: `=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",IF(ISBLANK(B2),A1+1,A2))`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

Public Sub GroupCells()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstBlankRow As Integer, lastBlankRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim neighborColumnValue As String

```
'select range based on given named range
Set myRange = Range("rngList")
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

firstBlankRow = 0
lastBlankRow = 0
'for every row in the range
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value
    neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column - 1).Value

    If (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
        'if cell is blank and firstBlankRow hasn't been assigned yet
        If firstBlankRow = 0 Then
            firstBlankRow = currentRow
        End If
    ElseIf Not (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
        'if the cell is not blank and its neighbor's (to the left) value is 0,
        'and firstBlankRow hasn't been assigned, then this is the firstBlankRow
        'to consider for grouping
        If neighborColumnValue = 0 And firstBlankRow = 0 Then
            firstBlankRow = currentRow
        ElseIf neighborColumnValue <> 0 And firstBlankRow <> 0 Then
            'if firstBlankRow is assigned and this row has a value with a neighbor
            'who isn't 0, then the cell one row above this one is to be considered
            'the lastBlankRow to include in the grouping
            lastBlankRow = currentRow - 1
        End If
    End If

    'if first AND last blank rows have been assigned, then create a group
    'then reset the first/lastBlankRow values to 0 and begin searching for next
    'grouping
    If firstBlankRow <> 0 And lastBlankRow <> 0 Then
        Range(Cells(firstBlankRow, myRange.Column), Cells(lastBlankRow, myRange.Column)).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Group
        firstBlankRow = 0
        lastBlankRow = 0
    End If
Next
```

End Sub